# coercing string to a Fixnum

Tags: ruby

I'm looking at some code written in Ruby 1.8 for RubyQuiz that is now throwing an error when I run it in 1.9.2. This method

```
def encrypt(s)
  return process(s) {|c, key| 64 + mod(c + key - 128)}
end
```

gives me the following error

```
in `+': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
```

Here's my code:

```
def mod(c)
  return c - 26 if c > 26
  return c + 26 if c < 1
  return c
end

def process(s, &combiner)
  s = sanitize(s)
  out = ""
  s.each_byte { |c|
    if c >= 'A'.ord and c <= 'Z'.ord
      key = @keystream.get
      res = combiner.call(c, key[0])
      out << res.chr
    else
      out << c.chr
    end
  }
  return out
end
```

Comment: Look up the function `mod`, I'm not sure if it's the new `modulo` function or something custom?

Comment: @Candide posted the mod function

Comment: Show also the process function

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use the '+' operator to add a String to an Integer. In IRB,

```
 irb(main):001:0> 1 + '5'
 TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

Or the other way around:

```
irb(main):002:0> '5' + 1
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String
```

You will have to first convert the string to a FixNum, i.e.

```
irb(main):003:0> '5'.to_i + 1
=> 6
```

or

```
irb(main):004:0> 1 + '5'.to_i
=> 6
```

The "to_i" will take in the integer part in the first part of the string and convert it to a FixNum:

```
irb(main):006:0> 1 + '5five'.to_i
=> 6
```

You might get unexpected results, however, when the string has no numbers:

```
irb(main):005:0> 1 + 'five'.to_i
=> 1
```

In your case, I think you are expecting an integer for the variable `key` but are getting a string instead. You might want to do `key.to_i`.
Hope this helps.